# Get the number of days of the current date with Time

Tags: c, date, timer

I'm trying to get the number of days untill today. Like:

```
int days, seconds;

seconds = Time(0); // Get the number of SECONDS from January, 1º 1970 untill now.  

days = seconds / (60 * 60 * 24);

printf("%d", days);
```

The output is: 16326.

But when I use some website that makes the conversion for you, they show 6464 days instead.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Sanity check: 1970 to 2014 is 44 years. Multiplying by 365 yields 16060. So your answer is probably correct.

Comment: What website did you use to check your conversion? Did you enter the date in their expected format? For instance, many Europeans use a dd/mm/yyyy format instead of the mm/dd/yyyy format that is common in the US.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice http://www.timeanddate.com/ is one of them. Try yourself, it says 6464 days. :( I'm getting crazy !

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing wrong. When I use that link, [I get 16,326 days](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=01&d1=01&y1=1970&m2=9&d2=13&y2=2014).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah, I suck. SOrry about that =\

Comment: No worries. Mistakes happen. It's good that you have tools to help you check your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. There are 30 + 14 = 44 years, which gives about 16000 days.